# PHP does not always find XML file

Tags: php, xml, linux, apache

I looked around for similar questions but found none identical, so here goes:

I have this webpage on a linux/apache server, the PHP script opens a XML-file upon every execution, the funny thing is that sometimes it can read the file and on some rare occasions it can not.. And when it cannot read it says that the file does not exist and to fix it I just have to refresh the page.

The XML file can be found in a sub directory (e.g. `/srv/www/page/subdir/file.xml`) and can only be changed manually and have the right privileges set (PHP can read and write to it).

I am using simplexml and the error I get is: `I/O warning : failed to load external entity`

So something strange is going on in the server, I just can't figure out what..

**Edit**: Adding some code

```
if ( !file_exists( $file ) )
{           
    error_log("File " . $file . " does not exist!");
    //return FALSE;
}

if ( $obj = simplexml_load_file( $file ) )
{
    // do stuff
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    error_log("Could not parse XML: " . $file );
    return FALSE;
}
```

---

**Solved**: error in code, not server

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: I accidentally submitted my question before finishing it..

Comment: Are you opening it for writing or reading?

Comment: Is the xml file in your server or are you fetching it from another website?

Comment: Show us some code/give more information. How are you opening the xml-file? Is it the same file every time, and if it is, is the file name hard coded in or is it dynamic? Is it on your server? Do you edit this xml file... etc. This is so vague that it will be hard to debug for you why your file says it does not exist...

Comment: are you fetching the file from external URL?

Answer (score 1):

There are no obvious explanation why the file is occasionally unavailable.  Could be a platform/OS issue, it's hard to tell.

However, you could apply this band-aid on the problem, it may unblock you if waiting up to 3 seconds makes the file "re-appear":

```
$count = 0;
$found = FALSE;
while( $count < 3 && !$found ) {
   if ( !file_exists( $file ) ) {
      $count++;
      sleep( 1 ); // sleep 1 second to see if the file appears on the next try
   } else
      $found=TRUE;
}

if( !$found )
  die("file not found after 3 attempts");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately though it did not work.. Tried waiting for 5 seconds if file was not found (trying every second) and the problem still stands.

Comment: It was worth a shot. ;)  Is it possible that on some invocation of your code, the $file variable is set incorrectly ?  var_dump( $file ) in the (!file_exists(..)) if statement to see if somehow it's getting corrupted or set incorrectly.

Comment: After some research I found out that the path sometimes does not update accurately when going into/out of subdirectories. The path was based upon session data that did not sync correctly (logic/code error).

Comment: Cool, I figured it might be something like a broken path/filename when the "multiple attempt" approach didn't help.